# iPhone - Play resource mp3 with MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to play a resource mp3 file with the MPMusicPlayerController or do I need to use the AVAudioPlayer API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should generally use `AVAudioPlayer` if you have just one MP3 file that you need to play. `MPMusicPlayerController` is designed to handle playlists of audio files and is fairly heavyweight in comparison.

Comment: That sounds sensible but do actually know whether it's possible to play this resource mp3, that's not in the iTunes library, using the MPMusicPlayerController API?

Comment: Yes, it is. You just need to instantiate it with `[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer]` rather than `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]`.